# Error's at XML file

Tags: android, xml

I am developing a small application. But I'm getting the below errors(2) at my XML code:
I'm new at this area. And I cant run the application. I need a little help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etTelefonePessoa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTelefone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTelefone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" //error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
 />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNomePessoa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvNome"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvNome"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
 />

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMostraDados"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
  />    

</RelativeLayout> // error: The element tag "textview" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</textview>"
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The errors are at the code...
 //error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
// error: The element tag "textview" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</textview>"

Comment: There are no errors in the XML you have shown.  Is this the *complete* file?

Comment: @user2830008 try the code given below and let us know if the problem still exists

Comment: try cleaning and re-building your project

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes eclipse give errors.Copy your code delete the the .xml file create new one and paste code again. I copy and paste your code it works just fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etTelefonePessoa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTelefone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTelefone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNomePessoa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvNome"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvNome"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMostraDados"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etTelefonePessoa"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:ems="10"
android:inputType="phone" 
  />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etNomePessoa"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_below="@+id/etTelefonePessoa"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
 />

 <ListView
android:id="@+id/lvMostraDados"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/etNomePessoa"
  />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'll remove the downvote if you say what you changed, why and how it fixes the problem.

Comment: @user2830008 was getting problem in the layout. He has not managed the views. Hes using relative layout so he has to mention the position properly. And this code is working fine. In his code, the views were overlapping. Thats it.

Comment: and there are no parsing errors in the OPs XML either!  You cannot post an answer without explaining why and how if fixes the problem.

Comment: He is confused. Its not parsing error. Its positioning error. He is unable to see the 2 views because of overlapping.

Comment: Really?  `Error parsing XML: mismatched tag` and `The element tag "textview" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</textview>"` and `I cant run the application`